# put balls in boxes with specific capacities

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have $10$ numbered balls and $3$ boxes with capacities: $5$, $3$ and $2$ balls. With how many ways can we put the balls in the boxes?
The boxes are distinguished.

I thought that it is like that:

$\binom{10}{5} \cdot \binom{5}{3} \cdot \binom{2}{2}$.Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: @evinde Just to get clear with the given problem. Is there also a distinction between the (numbered) balls ?

Comment: The boxes are distinguished..So,is the formula wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed, your answer is correct.

Comment: Nice,thank you amWhy !!!!